# How can I map two observable collections together?

Tags: silverlight, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I have an interesting problem. I have an existing module that exposes and maintains an observable collection of entities. I want to have an observable collection or some implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged that keeps in step with the adds and removals of items from the other collection but contains wrapper classes (view models) rather than the entities themselves.

I understand shallowly how the CollectionChanged event works, but I want to either handle that  completely which I'm not sure I know how to do, or otherwise use an existing pattern. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

[Continuous Linq](http://clinq.codeplex.com/) is designed to do exactly that.

Comment: Does this library work in Silverlight? Whenever I add the library as a reference to my project (using the Productivity Power Tools) it just kicks it back out again. :(

Comment: Doesn't look like this will help me with my Silverlight 4 based problem.

Comment: My apologies, I thought it had a Silverlight build. I'll dig up an example of doing it the hard way.